# PHP Variable Concatenation Inside Line of File

Tags: php, file, concatenation

I have some PHP code on my site that reads a line from a file and `echo`s that line. In one of these lines of cade I have placed a variable concatenation in the form of `{$varname}`, but in the end result it actually echos {$varname} instead of switching it with the variable.

The line reads:

`<p>Today's date (at the server) is {$date}.</p>`

The code used to echo the line reads:

`$line = fgets($posts);`
`echo $line;`

And the output of that code is: 'Today's date (at the server) is {$date}.'

And the variable `$date` is declared earlier in the code. I am wondering if there is some special way of doing this for lines in a file, or if I'm not doing this right?

EDIT: The output is also available at http://codegamecentral.grn.cc/main/?pageNumber=2.

ANOTHER EDIT: This code is run through a while loop until it reaches the end of the file, read line by line. This should preferably be a fast solution that will not cause problems when used with a string that doesn't contain `{$date}`.

Comment: `{<?php echo $date; ?>}` this might help

Comment: The answers below seem to provide a nice solution, but, without seeing too much of the code, if the `{$date}` is "supposed" to be replaced in the code already but isn't, then the problem is likely that you're using single quotes `'` rather than double quotes `"` in the string. PHP interprets `'{$var}'` as a literal string versus `"{$var}"` as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a line as text, and PHP substitution won't work unless it's done against *code*.

You need some more complicated processing (or to tell PHP to consider that text as if it was code, by using `eval`; which is strongly discouraged for security reasons, and may not work everywhere since the `eval` function is sometimes disabled by webmasters, for those same security reasons).

The most powerful alternative would be to use `preg_replace_callback` to recognize text sequences such as `{$varname}` and replace them with `$varname`. Of course `$varname` would need to be defined, or checked for existence:

```
function expandVariables($text, $allowedVariables) {
    return preg_replace_callback('#{\$([a-z][a-z_0-9]*)}#i',
        function($replace) use ($allowedVariables) {
            if (array_key_exists($replace[1], $allowedVariables)) {
                return $allowedVariables[$replace[1]];
            }
            return "NO '{$replace[1]} VARIABLE HERE.";
        },
        $text
    );
}

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$line = '<p>Now (at the server) is {$date}.</p>';

$vars = get_defined_vars(); // LOTS of memory :-(

// better:
// $vars = array ( 'date' => $date, ... ); // Only allowed variables.

$eval = expandVariables($line, $vars);

print "The line is {$line}\nand becomes:\n{$eval}";
```

Outputs:

```
The line is <p>Now (at the server) is {$date}.</p>
and becomes:
<p>Now (at the server) is 2014-10-12 18:36:16.</p>
```

## Caveats

This implementation is more secure than straight `eval()`, which would execute *any PHP code at all* it were to find in the read line. **But** it can still be used to output the content of any defined variable provided the attacker knows its name and is allowed to request it; an admittedly unrealistic example would be `<p>Hello, {$adminPassword}!</p>`.

To be more secure still, albeit at the expense of flexibility, I'd endorse Viktor Svensson's solution which only allows very specific variables to be set, and is both simpler and faster:

```
// Remember to use 'single quotes' for '{$variables}', because you DO NOT
// want expanded them in here, but in the replaced text!

$text = str_replace(array('{$date}', '{$time}' /*, ...more... */),
                    array(date('Y-m-d'), date('H:i:s') /*, ...more... */),
                    $text);
```

Also, you might be interested in checking out some templating solutions such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

## Processing a whole file

To process a whole file, if memory is not an object, you can in both cases (preg and str_) load the whole file as an array of lines:

```
$file = file($fileName);
```

and use `$file` as subject of the replace. Then you can iterate on the results:

```
// replaceVariables receives a string and returns a string
// or receives an array of strings and returns the same.
$text = replaceVariables($file, $variables);

foreach ($text as $line) {
     // Do something with $line, where variables have already been replaced.
}
```

## Speed

Something one doesn't often appreciate is that regular expressions are **fast**. I don't know what text-matching algorithm `str_replace` employs (I *think* Boyer-Moore's), but preg has the advantage of being Perlishly array-aware. It has a heavier setup (linear on the dictionary size), but then it "scales" better in the replacement time, while `str_replace` is constant setup, scales linearly in the replacement time. Which means `preg_replace` will save huge amounts of times in massive replacements; it fares worse in simpler contexts.

*Very* roughly, run time is (S + R*L*V)*V ( V = number of variables, L = number of lines ) where preg_replace has a detectable S and a negligible R, while str has the reverse. With large values of V you really want the smallest R you can get, even at the expense of an increase in setup time S.

```
Dependency on Variable N.. ? variables, 18 lines, keylen 5, vallen 20
v       preg advantage
5       -82%
15      -55%
25      -2%
35      14%
45      65%
55      41%
65      51%
75      197%
85      134%
95      338%

Dependency on File length. 32 variables, ? lines, keylen 5, vallen 20
l       preg advantage
5       -31%
15      -33%
25      14%
35      80%
45      116%
```

Of course, *maintainability* is also an issue - `str_replace` does it in **one** line of code, and the function itself is maintained by the PHP team. The function built around `preg_replace` requires as much as 15 lines. Granted that, once tested, you shouldn't need to modify it any longer, just pass it a dictionary.

## Looping

Finally, you may want to use variables *referring other variables*. In this case neither preg nor str_ will work reliably, and you will have to implement a loop of your own:

```
<?php
$file   = "This is a {\$test}. And {\$another}. And {\$yet_another}.\n";

$vars   = array(
    "test"  => "test",
    "another" => "another {\$test}",
    "yet_another" => "yet {\$another} {\$test}",
);

$text = preg_replace_callback('#{\$([a-z][a-z_0-9]*)}#i',
    function($replace) use ($vars) {
        if (array_key_exists($replace[1], $vars)) {
            return $vars[$replace[1]];
        }
        return "NO '{$replace[1]} VARIABLE HERE.";
    },
    $file
);

$keys   = array_map(function($k){ return "{\${$k}}"; }, array_keys($vars));
$vals   = array_values($vars);

$text2  = str_replace($keys, $vals, $file);

$text3  = $file;
do {
    $prev   = $text3;
    $text3  = str_replace($keys, $vals, $text3);
} while ($text3 != $prev);

print "PREG: {$text}\nSTR_: {$text2}\nLOOP: {$text3}\n";
```

The output is:

```
PREG: This is a test. And another {$test}. And yet {$another} {$test}.
STR_: This is a test. And another {$test}. And yet {$another} {$test}.
LOOP: This is a test. And another test. And yet another test test.
```

Comment: The smaller script at the bottom looks better for me, as this is being looped in a `while` statement (so the faster the better), but I was wondering if this will cause any unwanted side-effects if used on a string that doesn't have `{$date}` in it?

Comment: It shouldn't. The tokens that are not there of course have no effect, aside from a negligible processing delay. Also, perhaps you can do without the `while`.

Comment: Wow, this is a lot of effort put into this! I doubt I will be using multiple variables in any of the lines, and the size of the lines will (probably) not get too big, but I will keep these in mind, and remember this for if I do make something that would need them. I think for now I will start with the smaller `str_replace` but later may move to some of these others. Thanks! (I would upvote this but my level isn't high enough)

Answer (score 3):

How about a `string_replace()`?

```
echo str_replace('{$date}', $date, $line);
```

Comment: This is often how people do templating, but in order to avoid the confusion between a variable and a sort of "token" to be replaced, they use a different syntax, so, instead of `{$date}`, they'd use `%date%`. If you do the latter, then you can also write a function that does: `return str_replace("%{$key}%", $value, $line);` dynamically over an array that is constructed, respectively `$key => $value`.

Comment: Will this solution also work with a string that does not contain `{$date}`? (every line is printed within a `while` loop that loops to the end of the file, not every line contains the variable)

Comment: If a string doesn't include the keyword (`{$date}`), nothing will be replaced (the line will be "skipped").

Comment: For now I am going to use this one, but I accepted a post below because it has many more options which I may need in the future, and includes this one (with a reference to you). I would upvote this, but I'm not level 15 yet.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do what you want:

```
eval("\$line = \"$line\";");
echo $line;
```

**Warning:**
Although this will do the job, I would strongly discourage you from doing it unless you have 100% certainty that only you or trusted people can generate the files that will be evaluated this way because `eval()` can run any PHP code inside the variable.